# Mutli Label Classifier Accuracy is Not Increasing of Keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am doing transfer learning of a pre-trained keras vgg16 model. My dataset has 10,000 examples and 14 labels.
dataset looks like this

```
No finding | Cardiomegaly | ---- | Fracture |
   0.0           0.0                 1.0
   1.0           0.0                 0.1
```

further code of the model is below. The gf is the dataframe containing labels data in the form of 0's and 1's.

````
train_data, val_data = train_test_split(gf, test_size=0.2)
import tensorflow as tf
datagen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                             samplewise_center=True,
                             samplewise_std_normalization=True,
                             rotation_range=40,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             fill_mode='nearest')

train_flow = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_data,
    directory=image_dir,
    x_col="Path",
    y_col=train_data.columns[5:], # assuming the labels start from the 6th column
    target_size=(224, 224), # assuming you want to resize the images to 224x224
    class_mode="raw",
    batch_size=20,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 42
)
val_flow = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=val_data,
    directory=image_dir,
    x_col="Path",
    y_col=val_data.columns[5:], # assuming the labels start from the 6th column
    target_size=(224, 224), # assuming you want to resize the images to 224x224
    class_mode="raw",
    batch_size=20,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 42
)

base_model = keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights="imagenet",  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    include_top=False,
)  

base_model.trainable = False

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
# We make sure that the base_model is running in inference mode here,
# by passing `training=False`. This is important for fine-tuning, as you will
# learn in a few paragraphs.
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
# Convert features of shape `base_model.output_shape[1:]` to vectors
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# A Dense classifier with a single unit (binary classification)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(14, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```[![dataset image bar graph][1]][1]
````

accuracy is not increasing from 14. I have tried with both sigmoid and softmax at last layer. Further I have tried with binary_crossentropy and cetgorical_crossentropy. Changed learning_rate several times (0.001, 0.0001). I have also used different architect like Xecption, vgg AND mobilenet. I also changed this data from points to integers.

I have also plotted bar group of the labels in my CSV. The shape of data that I am using can be seen below. I think there is no much class/label imbalance in among them.

[image: w]

Comment: Maybe your task is too different from that of pre-trained model. What are the input images, radiology picture? One way to figure out how to proceed with your task is to check Kaggle and find a competition similar to your task. Than see winner solutions/notebooks or high scoring public notebooks ('Code' section, sort by 'Best Score'). You might find eventually gut ideas there!

Comment: I didn't even realize this problem, will check it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your labels can be any floating point from 0 to 1 (in your example you have Fracture: 0.1 value). In this case may be "mse" loss (as well as metric) would be more suitable. The 'binary_crossentropy' loss is usually used when labels can be only 0 or 1.

Comment: I converted it just 0 and 1 but still the model is not increasing accuracy.